# Custom callback method when journal article expires in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I need to run custom code whenever an Journal Article expires in Liferay (in Java).

How can I register a callback function which gets called when an Journal Article changes its state from approved to expired?

So I need to call a Java method which would receive the Article which expired as its parameter, or at least the Article's id.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Service Wrappers](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018159951-Overriding-Liferay-Services-Service-Wrappers-) come to my mind: *Everything* in Liferay goes through the technical API, and with a ServiceWrapper you can intercept and enrich calls to that API.

[Model Listeners](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017881252-Creating-Model-Listeners) work on the persisted objects themselves, but I'm more hesitant to recommend them - they're too far away from the business layer and rather on the persistence layer. I'd be *very* reserved putting any business logic down that layer.

Those plugin types work for any and all Entities created by Liferay's ServiceBuilder - and lucky you, Journal Article is such an entity. You'd likely look at a wrapper of JournalArticleLocalService.

Comment: Service wrappers are exactly what I needed. Thank you. :) I tested this and works as expected. I just now need to figure out which method does Liferay call when it expires the article automatically. I found which method gets called when I expire the article manually in CMS, and I need to find the one which gets called when article is expired by Liferay automatically.